# How does one use ZipInfo in Python?

Tags: python, zip, comments

Could someone please explain how exactly ZipInfo is supposed to be used? It says that ZipInfo.comment can access ["comment for the individual archive member"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo.comment)
I didn't even know archive members can have comments %\ ...

I tried getting it with:

```
data = zipfile.ZipFile('filename')
info = data.infolist()
```

but what I'm getting looks like:

```
   [<zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x0257DBF8>, <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x026A7030>, <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x026A7098>, ... ]
```

I don't know what that means :(

Also, i can't seem to call zipinfo.comment at all, but from above it looks like infolist() is the same thing?

So confused...

Comment: Are you indexing `info` first?

Comment: `info` ir probably a generator object. Try coercing it to a list: `list(info)`.

Comment: no, those are pretty much the first two lines of code... I've been fiddling with it for a while trying to figure out what does what... I can read off individual files with `data.read('zip member name').decode()`, but that just gives the contents, not the comments.

Comment: But did you try indexing `info`?

Comment: as in `print(list(info))` or `info = list(data(.infolist()))` ? I tried both and both gave the same result as before :I ....

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I'm not sure how to do that. You mean like this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_index.htm? How would that be helpful? It's already outputting a list, just not a list of what I thought it would output which is comments %\

Comment: ....... Like `info[0]`...

Comment: ... that just prints `<zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x0247DBF8>` ... why is the last part different every run?

Comment: no other suggestions? >.>

Answer (score 1):

Calling `data.infolist()` is giving you a list of [ZipInfo](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/zipfile.html#zipinfo-objects) objects. These are descriptions of all the individual files and directories stored inside your zip archive (and not the files/directories themselves). To manipulate these individual files/directories, you have to call a method of your ZipFile object `data` with the name from `info`. For example if you want to print the first 10 characters in each file you could run

```
for f in info:
    data.read(f)[:10]
```